# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles' Discord Self-Bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

Am using discord.py library to create a Discord self-bot that reads through a .txt file I already have filled with Discord IDs and checks their role in a guild server, if the role matches the role am looking for then their ID is saved in a new notepad called 'roletrue.txt'. I have been stuck for quite some time now, any help is appreciated! I know it is against Terms of Services however I still do it.

Code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # Read the file containing the Discord IDs
    with open("ids.txt", "r") as f:
        ids = f.read().split("\n")

    # Get the guild and the role
    guild = client.get_guild('GUILD_ID')
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="ROLE_NAME")

    # Iterate through the IDs
    for id in ids:
        # Get the member from the guild
        member = await guild.fetch_member(int(id))
        if role in member.roles:
            with open("roletrue.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"{id}\n")
            print(f"Discord ID {id} has the role {role.name}.")
        else:
            print(f"Discord ID {id} does not have the role {role.name}.")

client.run("TOKEN", bot = False)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\spath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\spath\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\NFT Vict Scrape\checkroles.py", line 13, in on_ready
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Customer")
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

I tried rewriting the code from scratch and check discord library and searched online and couldn't find a answer for my problem.

Comment: Seems like the `guild` that you got from `client.get_guild(guild_id)` is `None`, which means the guild that you are trying to find doesn't exist. Double check the `guild_id`

Comment: hello, I have checked the guild_id, it's correct and exists with in the token therefore there must be some other problem here.

Comment: Selfbotting is against Discord TOS. And ID's are ints, not strings, so `get_guild(string)` will never work...

Answer (score 0):

Change

`guild = client.get_guild("GUILD_ID")`

to

`guild = await client.fetch_guild("GUILD_ID")`

Get only returns the guild object if it's cached - if it's returning `None` then it's not so use `fetch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use await in order to fetch guild id and the roles from it,
try using this:

> guild = await client.fetch_guild("GUILD_ID")

or if it doesn't work, try using discord utils.